# How can I rename a webdav collection using Symfony Client?

Tags: php, symfony, webdav, symfony-http-client

I am using an http Client with Symfony. In this example I am creating a folder.

```
 $client = HttpClient::create();

 /* @var $response ResponseInterface */
 $createFolder = $client->request('MKCOL', $filePath, [
     'auth_basic' => [$user, $authKey],
 ]);
```

This works well.

Now I want to rename a folder:

```
 $renameFolder = $client->request('MOVE', $filePath, [
     'auth_basic' => [$user, $authKey],
 ]);
```

But what I cannot figure out is, where do I define the new folder name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be accessing a Webdav server, from the `MKCOL` command.

If you want to use `MOVE`, the destination should be passed on a `Destination` header, as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2003/aa142926(v=exchg.65)#example).

With [Symfony Http Client](https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html#headers), the request would be something like:

```php
$moveCollection =  $client->request('MOVE', $collectionPath,
    [
     'auth_basic' => [$user, $authKey],
     'headers'    => [
            'Destination' => $newCollectionPath
        ]
    ]
);
```

Comment: Still struggling with the error `Notice: Undefined offset: 1`.

Comment: Does the header path possibly not wokring because of the auth_basic?

Comment: Not likely. But that notice is not sufficient information to know what's going wrong, of if anything is going wrong at all.